# Query Parse database without using parse API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, parse-server

I'm looking at building a small nodeJs app which will query the parse database. (http://parseplatform.org/)
I'm fine connecting to the mongoDB and querying single collections but has anyone figured out how to use the pointers to join collections in a single query

Ideally using mongoose in node but if there is a better solution I'd be happy to try it.

I've done research and found a lot of people asking the same or similar questions but not found an answer to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're joining collections, which screams relational data, which noSQL isn't designed around solving.  You can use it to a certain extent, but it will only get you so far.  If you have relational data, use a relational database.
noSQL (mongo in this case..) is a document data store for storing "unstructured" data.

Some popular (free) relational db options are PostgreSQL or MySQL.